# MySQL Many-to-Many structure guidance?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Greets, diving into some MySQL and I've come across a stumbling block. I've read in multiple places that having a character-delimited setup is bad for multiple reasons. That I should be using a many-to-many setup. So I'll explain what I'm aiming for and what I have so far and would appreciate some guidance forward.

Table A - `characters`
characterID, name, etc, etc

Table B - `skills`
skillID, name, etc

Now characters are to battle, and will have skills that affect them as a character and take time to wear off, but also battle-specific skills.

So I create

Table C - `battlefx`
charID, SkillID, affect, etc

Table D - `herofx`
charID, skillID, affect, etc

The reason for the two different fx tables is some skills and affects would affect outside the specific battle, also would enable multiple participant battles.

My question is, am I thinking properly in my data structure? And then under each table I simply insert a row with the charID, skillID, etc for each individual affect? Will that be a hit to performance? Characters and battles will need to have multiple affects lasting their own amounts of time.

Comment: An fx is either 'battle' or 'hero', right? So why not have one fx table with a column identifying which. It also means you can add more scenarios - 'shopping', say - without adding more tables. But in general, you're thinking along the right lines. When performance becomes a problem, the game will either be big enough that it would justify professional support, or too big and successful for you to care.

Comment: That is a good point, I hadn't thought about combining fx tables, was too worried about performance hits due to my newb nature with mysql..

Generally speaking, I don't imagine the game would get more than a thousand heros in it, and each hero could technically have the fx from each skill/spell applied both as a battlefx or herofx.

Could I combine the tables and allow for duplicate entries? say FX1 is applied battle level for X fx, hero level for Y fx, and then if I added another situation later for Z fx?

Comment: In the first instance, I would probably handle that logic 'bit-wise': 1 = hero, 2 = battle, 3 = 1 + 2 = both